# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in EntityManager..getResultList()

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm having problems with persistence in java.

This is the method throwing the exception

```
public List<EscaleCatalogueKaravel> obtenirListeEscalesCroisiereAvecIdCroisiereKaravel(Integer idCroisiereKaravel, Integer refLangue) {
         List<EscaleCatalogueKaravel> listeEscales = entityManager.createQuery("select p from EscaleCatalogueKaravel p " +
                    "where p.idCroisiereComplete=:idCroisiereComplete and p.refLangue=:refLangue")
                    .setParameter("idCroisiereComplete", idCroisiereKaravel)
                    .setParameter("refLangue", refLangue)
                    .getResultList();

         if (listeEscales == null || listeEscales.size() == 0) {
            return null;
         }

         return listeEscales;
    }
```

The problem is that it's actually working, but sometimes it crashes in the **getResultList()** throwing this:

It is due to the type of List generated by the method? Anyways, there are no big differences between the working queries and the crashing ones. I mean all of them having more or less the same number of results.

Any suggestions?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.getInt(StringUtils.java:702)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.getInt(StringUtils.java:771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getInt(ByteArrayRow.java:109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getIntWithOverflowCheck(ResultSetImpl.java:7209)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2699)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2814)
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2101)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1380)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1308)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
    at $Proxy33.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.karavel.connectivity.gateway.croisiere.common.repository.impl.CatalogueKaravelRepositoryImpl.obtenirIdCroisiereCompleteAvecInfoCroisiere(CatalogueKaravelRepositoryImpl.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy23.obtenirIdCroisiereCompleteAvecInfoCroisiere(Unknown Source)
    at com.karavel.connectivity.gateway.croisiere.controller.service.RechercherCroisiereController.getItineraireCroisiere(RechercherCroisiereController.java:378)
    at com.karavel.connectivity.gateway.croisiere.controller.service.RechercherCroisiereController.obtenirListeCroisiere(RechercherCroisiereController.java:283)
```

EDIT to add more precision:

If I debug a litter bit deeper, I see the method throwing the exception

**Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.java**

```
private static class DeferredQueryInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

        private final Query target;

        private final EntityManager em;

        public DeferredQueryInvocationHandler(Query target, EntityManager em) {
            this.target = target;
            this.em = em;
        }

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            // Invocation on Query interface coming in...

            if (method.getName().equals("equals")) {
                // Only consider equal when proxies are identical.
                return (proxy == args[0]);
            }
            else if (method.getName().equals("hashCode")) {
                // Use hashCode of EntityManager proxy.
                return hashCode();
            }
            else if (method.getName().equals("unwrap")) {
                // Handle JPA 2.0 unwrap method - could be a proxy match.
                Class targetClass = (Class) args[0];
                if (targetClass == null || targetClass.isInstance(proxy)) {
                    return proxy;
                }
            }

            // Invoke method on actual Query object.
            try {
                Object retVal = method.invoke(this.target, args);
                return (retVal == this.target ? proxy : retVal);
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                throw ex.getTargetException();
            }
            finally {
                if (method.getName().equals("getResultList") || method.getName().equals("getSingleResult") ||
                        method.getName().equals("executeUpdate")) {
                    EntityManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager(this.em);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To be exact:

```
Object retVal = method.invoke(this.target, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you the list is not null and contains a single element.  In that case array.get(1) will cause an error as array.get(0) is the first element.  Perhaps you can log the array size and see if the size matches your expectations.

Comment: Thanks. I edited to add more precision to debug. I'm not doing the get() manually. It's the own function, so I can do nothing there

Comment: Well, seems to be a problem when using the alias "p". If I use column names works fine... but thank you!